# Uploading File to GCS Bucket in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have an Airflow DAG with a variable set as a GCS bucket as follows:

```
bucket = 'customer_accounts'
```

When I run my Airflow DAG, everything works fine and a CSV file is uploaded into the `customer_accounts` bucket.

Now, I want to create a folder in the `customer_accounts` bucket and send all the CSV files from the DAG to the following folder in the bucket.

```
bucket = 'customer_accounts/canada'
```

However, when I try to run my DAG with `bucket = 'customer_accounts/canada'`, I am getting an error message of an invalid bucket name.  Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: bucket is still `'customer_accounts'` - you should include folder into file name

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the bucket is still `'customer_accounts'`, Google Cloud Storage doesn't have the concept of folders in a traditional sense, they are part of the filename. You can learn more here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork.